# Child Pointer Segfault when Parent Pointer Changed

Tags: c

I have a parent structure that contains a child structure within it, as well as a pointer to a union which points to the child. My problem is that the sample code below works, until I want to point my pointer to my parent structure to another instance of my parent structure at which point my internal pointers seems to break and cause segfaults. I can get around this by updating the internal pointers every time I change where the parent points but am hoping to avoid that. I thought that since internally the structure is not changing that the internal pointers would still be setup to point to the correct offset from the new parent address but it seems I am mistaken?

Can anyone help me out, below I have sample code (please disregard the pointlessness of my example, my situation is much more complex and there is a reason for this but the example illustrates my issue).

Here is a simplified version of my scenario:

```
typedef struct mychildstruct
{
   uint16_t member
}mychildstruct;

typedef union myunion
{
   mychildstruct child;
   uint16_t a;
}myunion;

typedef struct myparentstruct
{
   mychildstruct child;
   myunion *union;
}myparentstruct;

myparentstruct parent;
myparentstruct *parent_ptr;

parent_ptr = (myparentstruct *)&parent;
parent_ptr->union = (myunion *)&parent.child;
```

No problems here and reading or writing to `parent_ptr->union->child` works fine and correctly points to the same memory location as `parent_ptr->union->a`. However if I do this:

```
myparentstruct parent2;

parent_ptr = (myparentstruct *)&parent2;
```

Then `parent_ptr->union->child` and `parent_ptr->union->a` segfault.

Is there a way around reassigning the correct memory address to `parent_ptr->union` every time I change `parent_ptr`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `parent2` is unitialized. What do you expect `parent2.union` to point to?

Comment: Maybe you have oversimplified your problem, but once you assign `parent_ptr` to point to a different structure, it points to a different structure.  That you have modified some *other* structure via a *different* pointer value that used to be stored in the same variable has no bearing whatever on the new pointer target.

Comment: yes I am realizing now that pointers are absolute, in order for my child pointers to remain intact I would have to use pointer math relative to the parent pointer to have them remain associated with the expect memory locations

Comment: I will attempt the relative pointer solution I have in my head and post the answer if it works...I may have explained my dilemma poorly and posting the answer may help clarify and help someone in a similar situation.

Comment: If you do get something that works then I am eager to see it, in part because I'm still not grasping how anything remotely like what you describe could work.  In particular, although yes, pointers are absolute, that does not appear to be your root problem.  I don't think you're fully or properly distinguishing among your pointer variable, its value at any given point, and the objects to which its various values point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: **NO!** there is no way around reassigning in your example.

It does not matter if you use use an absolute or relative pointer.
Pointer arithmetic will not help you.

In your example, you allocate (statically, on the stack) 2 separate structures:
`parent` and `parent2`.

Each of them occupies separate memory areas, and in each there is a `union` pointer of its own. A completely separate `union` pointer!

In your code, you initialize the `union` pointer belonging to `parent`.
But then, you try to access `union` pointer belonging to `parent2`.
Which you did not initialize, and so you get segmentation fault.

Lets simplify your example event further:

```
myparentstruct parent;
myparentstruct parent2;

parent.union = &parent.child;
parent2.union->a;
```

This will still get a segfault. And this code is completely equivalent to what you are attempting.

Nothing you do with pointers will automatically initialize two separate variables at the same time...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I was worries about that. My actual code has 5 different child pointer unions and I was hoping to avoid having to reassign them every time I changed the parent pointer. I just made a little help function to reassign them, that will have to do I guess.

Comment: You would not have to reassign them every time, just once after you allocate the parent structure. But making function for it  was a good idea. Think of it like a `constructor`. Though C does not have specific syntax for OO programing, you can still use it like OO language if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `parent2` but you haven't initialized it. Additionally, looking through your example code you've provided, you haven't allocated space for anything with `malloc()`. Without seeing your actual code, I can't really tell you where you're going wrong. Maybe you are allocating space or did initialize `parent2` but it isn't shown.